# Memory Mapped File Code Not Working Correctly in C++

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to read large files by mapping them to the memory for better efficiency. After opening the file, creating memory map object, and view, I am trying to access the values in the file by dereferencing the pointer to the memory, but I am not getting the actual values in the file.

For a small experiment, I am trying to read the values in the following file "test.txt" which includes 4 integers as 
    1 2
    3 4

Here is my code.

```
HANDLE hCreateFile;
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPVOID lpMapAddress;
char tempFile[200];
strcpy(tempFile,"C:\\...\\test.txt");
hCreateFile = CreateFile(tempFile,GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   //Opens the "tempFile" and returns an handle to the file

if(hCreateFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cout<<"Problem opening the file"<<std::endl;
}

hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hCreateFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
if(hMapFile == 0)   {
    std::cout<<"Problem creating map file object"<<std::endl;
}

lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
if(lpMapAddress == 0){
    std::cout<<"Problem viewing the file"<<std::endl;
}

int* mp = (int*)lpMapAddress;
std::cout<<"The first dose value is "<<*mp<<" ";
std::cout<<"The second dose value is "<<*(mp+1)<<" ";
std::cout<<"The third dose value is "<<*(mp+2)<<" ";
std::cout<<"The fourth dose value is "<<*(mp+3)<<;
```

From this code, the output that I expect to get is
    1 2 3 4

However, I am getting something like this
    221388849 874525450 0 0

Could anybody help me with what I am doing wrong in the code above? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to read Char values as Int values.  Since an Int is 4 Bytes (usually), then *mp would be the combination of the four ascii values for '1', ' ', '2', and ' '.  Note that the Ascii value for '1' is not 1.  *(mp+1) would be '3', ' ', '4', and ' '.  Then the last two values are null.  Btw - this problem seems to have nothing to do with using Memory Mapped files or not.

Comment: @ Steven Hansen I understand that *mp corresponds to '1',' ','2', ' '. So, in this case, do I need to use a char pointer in dereferencing them and then cast it to int? e.g., char* mp = (char*) lpMapAddress and then int(*mp)? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a char* if you have single digit numbers, but you can't cast them to an int.  You should probably use one of the functions from the atoi family, which would also support numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: @StevenHansen Thank you Steven, Bubbafat and Ajay for your comments. I was able to use memory mapped files to map large files (int or double) into memory and read them from the memory instead of using ifstream class. This gives me around 5 times speedup for double files and 15 times speedup for int files which is exactly what I wanted to see. Your comments were helpful for me to read the data correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are reading ASCII data and expecting a magical conversion to integers.

Think about what the text is:

"1 2 3 4"

Now your first value:  221388849

The is 0x0D322031

0x31 = "1"
0x20 = " "
ox32 = "2"

... and so on.

Comment: Ok, so from your and Steven's comment, I understand that *mp is the combination of '1',' ','2', ' '. So, does 221388849 correspond to this? I didn't understand that part. Thank you.

Comment: I explained what 221388849 was.  What don't you get?

Comment: The numbers are stored little endian.  Read back to front.  The continuation is 3420330A which means you have a CRLF between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a simple text file using file mapping APIs, doesn't sound good. Get a grip on how to read a simple text file - using more simpler functions like `fopen`/`fscanf`, or `ifstream` class. Then understand reading the same file using `CreateFile` and `ReadFile`. Using File-mapping is a big no-no unless you understand what is text file and what is binary file (which *actually* is nothing - it is just how you open a file).

To open file in text-mode you use `fopen` with **t** option (which is default for this function). To open in binary-mode you need to explicitly give **b** mode.

A number `1` stored in file doesn't mean value 1. It is actually 49. Since ASCII of `1` is integer 49. You are attempting to read this value (one byte) in integer. Integer is 4-bytes (generalized, and assumed for your case). Out of which rest of 3 bytes would be garbage (which three - first 3 or last three - you figure out!!). Only 1 byte (first or last of int-4-byte), would be `1` having value 49. You would never get `1` in one, two or four byte integer (you'd get 49 only).

Since "1 2 3 4" is stored in file, '1` (49), space (ASCII 32) ... is stored. You might get following sequence:

49, 32, 50, 32, 51, 32 ...

Parse first four bytes into this integer (using Windows 7 calculator in programmer mode).

There is lot to understand...

Comment: @ Ajay Ok. The text file that I am trying to read is around 40 MB including multiple lines of integer data. Right now, I am getting each line as a string and then parsing the string into integers using istringstream class and then adding each integer value in its vector (i.e, for each line there is a corresponding vector). Right now, all of this takes around 10 sec, but I would like to speedup (10 times is desirable). For this reason, I thought that I could use memory mapped files which I have little knowledge about.

Comment: @ Ajay Below is my code, so is there a faster way to read the data without using mapped memory files? Or is that the only way in this case? Thank you for your help.

Comment: std::ifstream input;
 input.open(tempFile);
 i = 0;
 while(getline(input,s)) {
  std::istringstream ss(s);
  while(std::getline(ss,r,',')) {
   std::stringstream convert(r); //convert r to int y
   convert>>y;
   b[i].setv(y); //b is the vector of objects. b[i] is the vector of int (each y is push backed to the vector)
  }

  i++; //i corresponds to each row
 }

Comment: Memory mapped files doesn't offer faster reading than `ReadFile` API. Speedup is dependent on many factors: Debug or Release build, how large data you are reading in one API call, the speed (and defragmentation status) of the disk. String reading and parsing is second aspect. Don't mix!